# Data flow of a Struts Framework

Tags: java, struct

I want to know data flow in the `Struts 1.2` framework . 
I found Different **components** like

1. struts.XML
2. action class
3. form class
4. Vo class
5. Dao class

After studying a lot I came know that `dao` act as communicator with `database`. One thing I can't understand is the form concept of struts and what is the `vo` class means? How `vo` class is populated using the value given in the front end.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well todays world belong to new generation of MVC frameworks like Struts 2, Spring MVC etc which helps developer to focus on their core work in cleaner,modular and scalable style. If you are learning better to start with them. But if you are working on some legacy project then it makes sense. I used to work on struts 1.2 9 years before. Here is what i recall

Major components are Jsp(View), Action(controller), Form(Model/backing bean for form populated data ).

When you submit the form on jsp, request goes to web.xml where it founds the mapping for Struts 1.2  front controller, This controller internally resolves the request path mapping  from struts.xml and inititates the action. Front controller also populates the form bean from request parameter and supplies it as mathod parameter to called action method. Main point to remember is there will be single  instance of action class per container, so it should be stateless.  There are different kind of actiona which you can explore further.

VO are the value objects . Some calls them domain objects(DO)/Data Transfer Objects(DTO)/Java beans.
Basically they represent the represent the persistent entity in Database and act as a carrier.

DAO/Service layer is not a part of struts framework. Its your business layyer. Basically struts work ends at action class beyond which it further delegates the call to service layer.

Comment: yes M Sach I am working upon this framework .it is very useful info for me . if anything required i will get back to you soon. 
thank you :)

Comment: Hello Sach ... In pojo we need to have a table for each bean class. Here in struts is it a optional thing ???